# Array object assertion without knowing it's position in Karate Framework

Tags: api, karate

I am adding user into array using post call and I want to make assertion but I don't know the position of the object I added into the Array and also there is duplicate entry of the user so how can I assert the user which I recently added into array.

```
{
    "message": {
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "Ashish Patil",
                "weight": "65"
            },
            {
                "name": "Ashish Patil",
                "weight": "65"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

this is the example so how I get to know which user added recently.

Comment: this question doesn't make any sense. do you mean that checking if 2 users are there with the same name is enough ?

Comment: there are multiple users and then I added one duplicate entry having common keys and values and I don't know the exact index number how can I make assertion in this case.

Comment: I think you are expecting too much from JSON. I give up here, hopefully someone else will understand what you are asking for and help. all the best !